# Cannot able to run my application?

Tags: android, mobile-application

I'm following the book "Professional Android 2 Application Development" by Reto Meier.  I created the "HelloWorld" project.  I use Eclipse as an IDE.  If I run the application then the simulator starts but my application cannot run.  he following information is displayed in the console:

```
[2011-07-03 16:03:28 - Hello_world] ------------------------------
[2011-07-03 16:03:28 - Hello_world] Android Launch!
[2011-07-03 16:03:28 - Hello_world] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-03 16:03:28 - Hello_world] Performing com.paad.HelloWorld.Hello_worldActivity activity launch
[2011-07-03 16:03:28 - Hello_world] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'device2_1' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-07-03 16:03:28 - Hello_world] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'device2_1'
[2011-07-03 16:03:56 - Hello_world] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-07-03 16:03:56 - Hello_world] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-07-03 16:05:12 - Hello_world] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.paad.HelloWorld.Hello_worldActivity activity launch'!
```

I cannot understand why my application is not able to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you wait until the emulator finished starting?
The log you posted may indicate that you closed the emulator before it started up.
The start takes a while, depending on the device configuration you have chosen (up to 5 minutes for me, if I try to launch a tablet emulator).
While starting, it goes to a small text saying "android" to an android text-logo and after that its usually up

And did you unlock them emulator? The emulator behaves like a real phone, 
there is the usual key-lock in place. You have to release that first,
depending on the android version your are using you either have to drag a handle sideways
or press the menu key (e.g. in Android 1.6). If the phone is locked, you cant launch your app. There should be some info text on the screen telling you what to do.

After you got that, try to run your app again. It should start. 
Please note that you can leave the emulator open once you started it.
If you run your application, the newest version will always be uploaded into the
emulator and executed. No need to restart the emulator all the time (which takes ages).

Answer (score 1):

Android has some very good official documentation and tutorials.  I suggest you try starting with the "official" [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) example.  I started there with my first Android app, and it worked as advertised for me.

Comment: i also try the examples given the android official but i get the same result.The simulator starts but my application cannot running

Answer (score 1):

You could post your code so we can see possible problems.

You can also look at warnings and errors with LogCat (Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS or something). Then use Log.d or Log.e in your code so you can trace how far it gets before messing up.

Comment: I cannot understand ur concept.So please explain me.

Comment: Show us your Hello_world.java code. Put in a line like Log.d("Hello_world", "Testing 123"); Then lookup Eclipse and LogCat - it's a console with useful information. Chances are your program is causing an exception somewhere or the emulator isn't working properly.